# Propane Gas Safety

Tags: gas, propane

After sealing the propane gas supply line pipe threads, what is a safe wait time before using a propane clothes dryer?

Answer (score 1):

2 seconds. No dry time necessary.

Make sure to test the connection with gas leak detector, like Gasiola, before firing things up.